# Copy all images on system to one folder

Tags: bash, scripts

Im trying to create a bash script, that will search the system for images `jpg, jpeg, png, gif` and copy them to a new location. But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this.

This is what i have so far

```
#!/bin/bash
STRING="Copy system images \n"
echo $STRING

# settings
$LOCATION = ~/backup/images/$(date)
$FILETYPE = jpg, jpeg, png, gif

# in PHP
# preg_replace("/[^, ]+/", "*.$0", $input_lines);
# bash?? filetype should be *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png, *.png

# find all images defined in FILETYPE
find ~/ -type f -iname $FILETYPE > images.txt 
&& echo "Number of images loccated: " 
&& wc -l images.txt

# read every line (image path), and copy to new location.
&& while read line; do cp $line ~/backup/$line; done < images.txt
&& rm images.txt
```

I know, it might be a little overkill. But and automated script would be great!

As you can see, i don't know how to sed, preg_replace the `$FILETYPE`. And the excessive use of `&&` seems not right?

Comment: I can only see invalid syntaxes..

Comment: Personally, I'd change FILETYPE from variable to an array, and loop over each one , running `find ~/ -type "$TYPE "  or something like that on each iteration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find all files in the home directory with `jpg`, `jpeg`, `png`, or `gif` extensions and copy them to `~/backup`, try:

```
cd
find . -regex '.*\(jpg\|jpeg\|png\|gif\)' \! -path './backup/*' -exec echo cp -t backup {} +
```

#### How it works

- `cd`

  This makes the home directory, `~/`, be the same as the current directory, `./`.
- `find .`

  Look for files in the current directory
- `-regex '.*\(jpg\|jpeg\|png\|gif\)'`

  Restrict the results to files whose names end with `jpg`, `jpeg`, `png`, or `gif`.
- `\! -path './backup/*'`

  Omit files that are already in the backup directory.

  Note that while `-regex` expects a *regular expression* as its argument,  `-path` expects a *glob*.  These are two very different forms which obey very different rules.
- `-exec echo cp -t backup {} +`

  Move the files found to the backup directory.

Comment: I would suggest `cp` over `mv` because I'd want to keep the files where they are and only copy them to a back up disk.

Comment: @grooveplex Thanks for spotting that.  Answer updated to copy rather than move.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one which works like a charm.
It adds the EPOCH time to prevent overwriting files with the same name.

```
cd /media/myhome/'Local station'/
find . -path ./jpg -prune -o -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec sh -c '
for file do
   newname="${file##*/}"
   newname="${newname%.jpg}"
   mv -T -- "$file" "/media/myhome/Local station/jpg/$newname-$(date +%s).jpg"
done
' find-sh {} +
cd  ~/
```

It's been designed by Kamil in [this post here](https://superuser.com/questions/1640649/how-can-i-modify-path-coming-from-in-find-exec/1640808#1640808).